# How many USB flash-drive do I need to install FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd

I want to install FreeBSD from usb flash drive and I don't know how many usb flash drive do I need to install FreeBSD!

Comment: I don’t know if FreeBSD has a USB-based installer, but if it does, wouldn’t the answer depend entirely on the *size* of said drives?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, you can install FreeBSD from a USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mini-memstick and memstick images for each FreeBSD release ([example](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/11.1/)). The former is about 300 Mb and the latter is 700 Mb. Just `dd` these images to your flash.